# How to set the OAuth 2.0 state parameter in the Google API client library for python

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

Neither in the `oauth2client.client.OAuth2WebServerFlow()` constructor, nor its `step1_get_authorize_url` method accept a state parameter in any way. I know that I can store state in session cookies, but I'm still curious whether the library supports the state parameter in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is currently not possible. An issue was raised earlier to deal with that: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/170 but it has not been addressed yet.

Comment: They already did that for the PHP library (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php)